# EventLogReader Remote Performance

Tags: c#, .net, performance, event-log

I am using the EventLogReader to query remote 2008 servers for events. The performance of querying the events on a remote machine is horrible (6/sec). If I query the same machine via WMI using a forward-only ManagementObjectSearch the performance is great (1000/sec). I don't see any similar options on the EventLogReader (e.g. ReturnImmediatly, Rewindable) to speed it up. I tried turning off the firewall on the remote server to see if there was possibly communication issues, but that didn't make a difference.

When using EventLogReader to read logs from the local host the performance is as expected -- it's only over the network that it slows down (but WMI doesn't experience the problem).

Any way to speed up the performance of EventLogReader over the network?

Thanks,
Mitch

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't use WMI?

Comment: I need to get the events in ascending order (EventLogReader allows that). WMI only gives it back in descending.

Comment: how about use WMI to load them into memory, then sort them?

Comment: Loading a ManagementBaseObject into memory and sorting them results in unacceptable memory usage when you get any sort of large event pull (5000+ events). I had a pull that got up to 1.5G of memory...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did a little testing (modified the sample code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671200.aspx) and from my experimenting I found that the performance hit comes from calling EventRecord.FormatDescription().

When I only had a call to EventRecord.ToXml() I was able to pull remotely from a server on the LAN over 4300 events in 25 seconds at about 170 events/sec. When I added a call to EventRecord.FormatDescription() the performance dropped to almost 1.5 minutes to read all 4300+ events and about 52 events/sec.

I apologize this may not be the answer that you want but my advice would be if you don't need to call EventRecord.FormatDescription() it will increase performance quite a bit.

Comment: @Nate: thanks for looking into that. I am calling FormatDescription which I need to call to get the Message. I wonder if there is another way to get the interpolated message? I'll have to mess around with that.

Comment: I've found that EventRecord.ToXML() only outputs Application log messages, security logs seem to be built off of the event log properties, but FormatDescription() seems to be doing it painfully slow. I'm considering writing the full XPath for the security log details and falling back on FormatDescription if I don't have XPath data.

Comment: ^ Ignore that, it was a stupid idea, I have no clue how to basically compensate for FormatDescription being stupidly slow.